# how to edit property of UITableViewCell on other method

Tags: iphone, uitableview

i know it will be setup cell on this method

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

for example if i want to edit property of cell in

```
tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

how can i access to the cell that i selected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get visible cell in UITableView using following method:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

> **Return Value:** An object representing a
>   cell of the table or nil if the cell
>   is not visible or indexPath is out of
>   range.

So in your didSelectRow method you will have something like (you may need to set cell's selectionStyle to `UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone` to make your changes display properly):

```
- tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell != nil){
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }
}
```

Or you can subclass UITableViewCell, implement `- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated` method and change cell properties there.

Comment: could you please show me some example for me for first answer?

in the second answer, i think you told me to implement custom UITableViewCell and then override 
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated 
to handle right?